# Computations of Blow up

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

Let $V=Z(y^5-x^3(x+1))$ be an irreducible variety in $\mathbb A^2$.

The partial derivatives of the equation $y^5-x^3(x+1)$ at the point $p=(0,0)$ are:

$ \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}}=-3x^2-4x^3$,  $ \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}}=5y^4$,  then  $\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}} | _p=0=\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}} | _p$ i.e. $p$ is a singular point.

**1)** The equations of the blowing-up at $p$ in $\mathbb A^2\times\mathbb P^1$ are $xu=yt$ together with the morphism restriction $\pi:\Pi\to\mathbb A^2$ where $\Pi$ are given by the equation $xu=yt$ in $\mathbb A^2\times\mathbb P^1$.

**2)** In the affine chart $t=1$, we have

**a)** $y^5=x^3(x+1)$

**b)** $xu=y$.

Thus $Z(xu-y,y^5-x^3(x+1))=Z(y-xu,x)\cup Z(y-xu,x^2u^5-(x+1))$, and the exceptional curve is $Z(y-xu,x)=E$.

Then $E\cap V_1=\emptyset$ with $V_1=Z(y-xu,x^2u^5-(x+1))$

Thus look at the chart affine $u=1$

**3)** In the affine chart $u=1$, we have

**a)** $y^5=x^3(x+1)$

**b)** $x=yt$

In this case, $Z(xu-y,y^5-x^3(x+1))=Z(y,x-yt)\cup Z(y^2-t^3(yt+1),x-yt)$ and the exceptional curve is $E=Z(y,x-yt)$.

Then $E\cap V_2=\{(0,0,0)\}$ with $V_2=Z(y^2-t^3(yt+1),x-yt)$

Now calculate the matrix of partial derivatives of the equations of $V_2$; if $f=x-yt, g=y^2-t^3(yt+1)$

$\begin{bmatrix}{\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}}=1}&{\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}}=-t}&{\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial t}}=-y}\\{\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}}=0}&{\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}}=2y-t^3}&{\frac{{\partial g}}{{\partial t}}=-4t^3y-3t^2} \end{bmatrix}|_{(0,0,0)}= \begin{bmatrix}{1}&{0}&{0}\\{0}&{0}&{0}\ \end{bmatrix}$

Then the variety $\widetilde{V}$ is singular in $\pi^{-1}(p)$.

Is correct?

I have to do blowing up of the variety $V_2=Z(y^2-t^3(yt+1),x-yt)$ but now on $\mathbb A^3\times\mathbb P^2$?

They could help me do this please.

Comment: I think this is correct. Note however that singularities and blowing up are invariant by isomorphism and that the affine chart $u=1$ is isomorphic to the plane with $(y,t)$ as coordinates. In other words, $V_2$ is isomorphic to the plane curve $Z(y^2-t^3(yt+1))$. You can compute singularities and blow up the singularity with these coordinates. The computations are easier that way.

Comment: @Roland; I don't see why $V_2=Z(y^2-t^3(yt+1),x-yt)$ is isomorphi to $V_2=Z(y^2-t^3(yt+1))$?
In this case, the variety $V_2=Z(y^2-t^3(yt+1))$ I think in $\mathbb A^2$ and  the computations the blowing-up  again are in $\mathbb A^2\times \mathbb P^1$? Thanks

Comment: The isomorphism is given by $(x,y,t)\mapsto (y,t)$ and its inverse is given by $(y,t)\mapsto (yt,y,t)$ because $x-yt=0$ on $V_2$. So yes, you can compute the blow up of $V_2$ using the $(y,t)$-coordinates, that is as a subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^2\times\mathbb{P}^1$.